# What is a good alternative to webpack.DefinePlugin for create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I'm working on an ejected React application that uses webpack.DefinePlugin to store globally an object defining the folder names in the application for a specific path (kind of an ls in shell but using node fs)

I'm researching how to go back to the original create-react-app without loosing this functionality as some parts of the app relies on this, but I can't find anything other than a script that writes these names into a variable in js file prior to the commands npm start or npm run build.

The project is currently using Webpack 3 and Babel 6, the idea behind going back to react-scripts is get rid of the manual maintenance and simplify the project dependencies while upgrading the project

```
// analysis.js
module.exports = {
  key: values from fs node package
};



// WEBPACK
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "ANALYSIS": JSON.stringify(require('./analysis')),
    }),
```

I expect the same values to be available in the application without needing to eject react-scripts

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally chose to develop a script that runs before any webpack script and creates the file that I import later like any other file inside the React app

Regards